# Trying to display the reverse of a Many to Many Relationship in Django Admin

Tags: django-models, django-admin, many-to-many

Say I'm working on a database that tracks the members in different bands. Each Band will have multiple Musicians, but each Musician can only be in one Band. If my models look like this:

```
class Band(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField().primary_key = True
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2083, blank=True, null=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField('Musician', blank=True)

class Musician(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField().primary_key = True
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2083, blank=True, null=True)
    <NAME OF BAND>
```

After adding the Musicians in my db to the Bands, when I go to edit a Musician on the Admin page I want to see which Band they are in. What do I need to add to my models or my ModelAdmins to make that happen?

Right now where the above say  I have:
`member_of: Band.name`

I would expect that to return the name of the band but it's giving me the name of the Musician

Quick Edit: I forgot to mention that I have `readonly_fields = ["member_of"]` in my MusicianAdmin

Comment: Since it is a m2m, that means a `Musician` can belong to *zero*, *one* or ***more*** `Band`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify a `ManyToManyField` (or any other relation), you can query in reverse automatically with:

```
my_musician.band_set.all()
```

This is a `QuerySet` of all `Band`s related to the `Musician` named `musician`.

You can add these to your `ModelAdmin` for the musicians with:

```
class BandMembersInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Band.members.through


@admin.register(Musician)
class MusicianAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BandMembersInline,
    ]
```

> but each `Musician` can only be in one `Band`.

If each musician can only have one band, the modeling is wrong. In that case you model this with a [**`ForeignKey`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) from `Musician` to `Band`:

```
class Band(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2083)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Musician(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    band = models.ForeignKey(
        Band, related_name='members', on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

as admin, you can then use:

```
class MusicianInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Musician


@admin.register(Musician)
class MusicianAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …
    pass


@admin.register(Band)
class BandAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …
    inlines = [MusicianInline]
```